# Can't draw Serializable class on Unity Inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, drawing, editor, serializable, inspector

This is my Example class and MonoBehaviour script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class TestSerializableClass
{
    public int a;
    public string b;
}

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TestSerializableClass field1;
    [HideInInspector] public TestSerializableClass field2;
}
```

and this is the editor script for the MonoBehaviour Script

```
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(TestScript))]
public class TestScriptEditor : Editor
{
    SerializedProperty testClass;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();
        SerializedProperty testField = serializedObject.FindProperty("field2");
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(testField, true);

    }
}
```

[This is how my inspector for TestScript looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOKzd.png)

Why doesn't it draw the "field2" varialble like the first one?

Can I do it with Editor script and property field? How?

(the includeChildre flag is true)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the HideInInspector attribute from field2

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem!
You can't use DrawDefaultInspector() and draw the hided fields by yourself. 
You need to draw everything or nothing.